# Error De-Bugging: using cbind to move a column into another dataframe

Tags: r, cbind

I created a new dataset for character data, and want to move a column that is numeric into this dataframe, but I'm getting an error for some reason:

```
Column names In rawdata2: 
1                                 Data_Source
2                                   ID_Number
```

The column I want to move is ID_Number

I'm using this code:

```
characterdata <- dplyr::select_if(rawdata2, is.character)
characterdata <- cbind(characterdata, rawdata2[, c("ID_Number")])
```

The result is a column with this name: rawdata2[,c("ID_Number")].
Why doesn't it use the  original name "ID_Number"?

The following code worked fine when I did it for numerical variables, where I moved in a few character variables:

```
numericaldata <- dplyr::select_if(rawdata2, is.numeric)
numericaldata <- cbind(numericaldata, rawdata2[, c("Data_Source", "Location", 
"SectorCollapsed")])
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: `numericaldata <- dplyr::bind_cols(numericaldata, rawdata2[, c("Data_Source", "Location", "SectorCollapsed")])`

Comment: so use this code for character data? characterdata <- dplyr::bind_cols(characterdata, rawdata2[, c("ID_Number")])

Comment: Yeah try also `characterdata <- dplyr::bind_cols(characterdata, rawdata2[, c("ID_Number"),drop=F]) `

Comment: Sorry I don't understand whether to use bind_rows or bind_cols

Comment: Use `bind_cols()` sorry!

Comment: It's very strange, even when I do this, it doesn't carry over the column name...do you think there might be something wrong with the original column name?

Comment: Check the `str()` of your data and the `names()`

Comment: I just changed the name and this is the str:  $ RespondentID                             : num  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10. though I've changed the name, it doesn't matter, still giving me the same error in column name